# Unattended Ubuntu 12.04 Desktop installation Using Kickstart

Tags: installation, ubuntu-12.04, kickstart

I was trying to install  Ubuntu 12.04 Desktop  Using Kickstart from the tutorial [here](http://www.linuxuser.co.uk/tutorials/unattended-ubuntu-installations).

Here is **ks.cfg** file

```
#Generated by Kickstart Configurator
#platform=x86

#System language
lang en_US
#Language modules to install
langsupport en_IN ml_IN --default=en_US
#System keyboard
keyboard us
#System mouse
mouse
#System timezone
timezone America/New_York
#Root password
rootpw --disabled
#Initial user
user Test --fullname "Test" --iscrypted --password $1$N/vvAxo8$Q71h/eNwDh75x5IXQ8snN/
#Reboot after installation
reboot
#Use text mode install
text
#Install OS instead of upgrade
install
#Use CDROM installation media
cdrom
#System bootloader configuration
bootloader --location=mbr 
#Clear the Master Boot Record
zerombr yes
#Partition clearing information
clearpart --all --initlabel 
#Disk partitioning information
part swap --size 2048 
part / --fstype ext4 --size 1 --grow 
#System authorization infomation
auth  --useshadow  --enablemd5 
#Firewall configuration
firewall --disabled 
#Do not configure the X Window System
skipx
```

And my **isolinux/txt.cfg** look like

```
default autoinstall
label autoinstall
  menu label ^Automatically Install Ubuntu
  kernel /casper/vmlinuz
  append  file=/cdrom/preseed/ubuntu.seed boot=casper initrd=/casper/initrd.lz ks=cdrom:/ks.cfg –
label live
  menu label ^Try Ubuntu without installing
  kernel /casper/vmlinuz
  append  file=/cdrom/preseed/ubuntu.seed boot=casper initrd=/casper/initrd.lz quiet splash --
label live-install
  menu label ^Install Ubuntu
  kernel /casper/vmlinuz
  append  file=/cdrom/preseed/ubuntu.seed boot=casper only-ubiquity initrd=/casper/initrd.lz quiet splash --
label check
  menu label ^Check disc for defects
  kernel /casper/vmlinuz
  append  boot=casper integrity-check initrd=/casper/initrd.lz quiet splash --
label memtest
  menu label Test ^memory
  kernel /install/mt86plus
label hd
  menu label ^Boot from first hard disk
  localboot 0x80
```

I am getting lot of messages about installation progress, but after that the normal installation pop-up menu appearing(Try Ubuntu, Install Ubuntu etc..), on clicking that the normal installation begins as usual.

Does anyone faced such problem ?

am I doing anything wrong ?

Any help will be appreciated.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was also facing the same problem, while trying to install Ubuntu 12.04 Desktop automatically. It seems like the GUI is not taking the configurations set by kickstart.

But I was able to install Ubuntu 12.04 Server by this method. After installation, I have installed ubuntu-desktop packages so that I can make use of the GUI.

An alternative method is to download and install Ubuntu-12.04-alternate.iso. The installation is in text mode,so it accepts kickstart config file.

Regards,